# Get SelectedValue of dropdownlist which is created with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am filling dropdownlist with javascript.

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                    optn.text = array[i];
                    optn.value = array[i];
                    document.getElementById('<%=ddlProductModel.ClientID%>').(options.addoptn);
                }
```

But I can't get selectedValue of dropdownlist on postback in codebehind(c#). Any solution pls? Thanks.

Yasin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access selected element by `dropdownlist.SelectedValue` when values added on client side. Try to use `Request.Form["dropdownlistid"]`